# How to increase the adapter procedure timeout value in Worklight?

Tags: timeout, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

How can I increase the timeout value of a Worklight adapter procedure? My app crashes and I see the following in the exception details:

> "response [/apps/services/api/index/common/query] success: /*-secure-
>   {"responseID":"24","errors":["Invocation of procedure 'getFTTitle' has
>   timed out after 30
>   sec."],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/ "

Answer (score 6):

There are several places in Worklight where a timeout value can be specified:

CLIENT ----> WORKLIGHT SERVER -- (adapter) --> BACKEND

You can [increase the adapter procedure timeout](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/r__procedure_.html) (Worklight Server --> Backend) as follows:

```
<procedure name="nameHere" requestTimeoutInSeconds="valueHere"/>
```

I don't know what is your specific use case, so be sure to also [increase the client-side timeout](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_invokeprocedure.html). Have them match each other.

```
WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
    onSuccess : getDataSuccess,
    onFailure : getDataFailure,
    timeout   : valueHere
});
```

Also note that if you need to increase your timeout to a whole minute, consider that something may not be right here...

Comment: Idan, I have tried this and also "http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14871806" this solution...but no impact .

Comment: No impact in what way, it still fails are 30 seconds?

Comment: it seems defualt value not getting change

Comment: Sorry, my example was incorrect, I changed it to how it should be like based on the documentation in the IBM Information Center). Will need to verify if this happens or not...

Comment: I have tried both the solutions you have given but unfortunately timeout are not getting change.It fails at 30sec exactly.

Comment: Idan,one thing more.i'm not testing it in device..im testing in chrome webbrowser(with ripple)

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Just make sure you have re-deployed your adapter of changing the values.

Comment: Yes..i have re-deployed the adapter after changing it.but changed value didnt apply.procedure failed at 30sec

Comment: We've tested this and it is working. I don't know what is your specific use case, so make sure increase both the client and as well as adapter timeouts. See my edited answer above.

Comment: Please note that in the invokeProcedure options the timeout is in milliseconds not seconds. Refer to http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_client_invokeprocedure.html

Answer (score -1):

```
var wlInitOptions = 
{
    // # Worklight server connection timeout
    timeout: 60000,
    ...
}
```