# Blackberry App developed with worklight not working on gprs but working on wifi

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst

I have developed app in **worklight and build it for blackberry environment** which is **working fine on wifi** and I'm able to contact server which is having a public IP but whem I'm ***trying to use GPRS and connect the app to the server the app is unable to connect to the server.***Any solution for this problem???

Comment: Do you have any stacktrace from the device on trying to do this? Error logs or something?

Comment: Worklight version? BlackBerry 6? 7? 10? Are you running Worklight Server in Eclipse or on Application Server (Tomcat/WAS/Liberty)? Is the server accessible from the public internet?

Comment: running worklight server on tomcat, developing app for blackberry 7, worklight studio version 6.0 and "worklight server mobile foundation consumer edition 5.0.5" and yes the server is accessible from public internet and i'm using it for my android application

Comment: You should most definitely not mix Worklight Studio from v6 with Worklight Server from Worklight 5; always use the same version for Worklight Studio and Worklight Server.

Answer (score 0):

After the app failed connecting to the server, close the app and type alt+LGLG, this should open the device's log. See if you find anything Worklight-related in the log.

You can also verify that the Worklight Server is indeed open to the public by trying to load Worklight Console in your device's browser.

Comment: Yes I'm able to load the worklight console in my blackberry device browser
Log is as follows:
Name:LoggerWorklight
Severity:Error
GUID:c4535937abb8d5fc
Time:Aug 24, 2013 10:57:09
[http://publicIP/worklight/apps/services/api/BBTestApp/blackberry/init]
failure. state: 400, response: The server was unable to process the request from the application.
Please try again later.

Comment: Have you tried with a 3G connection or is this not available in your region? You can try increasing the server timeout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807821/how-to-increase-the-adapter-procedure-timeout-value-in-worklight

Comment: No 3g is not available and I have increased the timeout milliseconds in "initoptions.js" still it is giving me the same error

Comment: Can you try with a new app that the only change in it is setting connectOnStartup to 'true' in initOptions.js