# IBM Worklight 6.0.0.1 - Timeout setting in Adapters

Tags: timeout, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

How can I change the timeout when calling from the application to the adapter using `WL.Client.invokeProcedure`?

I have read the answer in the following post, but it is not working:
[How to increase the adapter procedure timeout value in Worklight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807821/how-to-increase-the-adapter-procedure-timeout-value-in-worklight)

**My configuration:**

*initOptions.js*

```
timeout: 600000
```

*Adapter XML*

```
<procedure name="addInsertarMensaje" securityTest="wl_unprotected" requestTimeoutInSeconds="600">
```

*Adapter invocation*

```
var timeout = 600000;
var invocationOptions = {
  onSuccess: successSynchDoc,
  onFailure: errorSynchDoc,
  invocationContext: context,
  timeout: timeout
};
```

**Android LogCat:**

```
12-02 11:23:04.603: D/Mapfre(21661): MyCustomTrace: Invoking the adapter

12-02 11:23:05.564: D/Mapfre(21661): Request [http://192.168.1.39:10080/xxx/apps/services/api/Mapfre/android/query]

12-02 11:23:26.214: D/Mapfre(21661): MyCustomTrace: After invoking the adapter

12-02 11:24:29.297: E/Mapfre(21661): [http://192.168.1.39:10080/xxx/apps/services/api/Mapfre/android/query] Host is not responsive. Try to manually access the URL through the android emulator browser to verify connectivity.
```

Is there a max value?

These are the traces in each part.

In the app:

```
12-02 14:30:24.473: D/Mapfre(8641): Custom Trace. Just befor WL.Client.invokeProcedure
12-02 14:30:25.103: D/Mapfre(8641): Request [http://192.168.1.39:10080/xxx/apps/services/api/Mapfre/android/query]
12-02 14:31:42.670: E/Mapfre(8641): [http://192.168.1.39:10080/xxx/apps/services/api/Mapfre/android/query] Host is not responsive. Try to manually access the URL through the android emulator browser to verify connectivity.
```

In the adapter receiving the invocation from the app:

```
[2/12/13 14:31:45:224 CET] 000000bf ht.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation I Custom Trace. Into Adapter implementation.
```

In the adapter receiving the answer from the host:

```
[2/12/13 14:33:34:714 CET] 000000bf ht.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation I Custom Trace. Received id: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

- The application is not calling the adapter. Basic diagram:

`Application << >>[ Worklight Server << >> Adapter ]<< >> Backend`

- Also, there is no maximum value Worklight imposes on timeouts. There's a default value, but you have changed it in all 3 locations.

Short explanation:

1. In **initOptions.js**, the `timeout` property relates to the amount of time the app will wait for a connection to the Worklight Server.
2. In the **adapter's XML**, the `requestTimeoutInSeconds` property relates to the amount of time the Worklight Server will wait for a response from the Backend.
3. In the **invocation options**, the `timeout` property relates to the amount of time the app will wait for a response from the Worklight Server.

In your case, the error points that you did not even reach the Worklight Server, let alone invoke the adapter procedure.

- Verify that your can reach the server; follow the instructions from the error message - try to load Worklight Console in your device's mobile browser
- Verify the device and server are in the same network
- Verify the firewall (if enabled) is not blocking any crucial ports or addresses

In case you did reach the Worklight Server, since obviously 600 seconds did not pass, I believe that the host is simply not reachable. Make sure that you are pointing to the correct host address and that nothing is preventing a connection to pass successfully.

If the host was found, and something else is not correct in the path or network, a response will be returned, but it will not wait 600 seconds.

Comment: I have edited the question with the traces in each part and the time stamps. The message being sent is 4mg message...

Comment: These 2 lines are not helpful; as written in the answer, please make sure the host is correct, follow the verification steps in the bottom part of the answer.

Comment: Why not? Everything is right. I reach the adapter, the adapter reach the host, and the adapter receives the host answer. So all the hosts (Worklight Server and Final Host) are being reached and are working. The only part not working is the app that throws a time out before the adapter returns the answer.