# IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to handle timeouts in slower networks?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We have built an application using `Worklight 6.1` for `iOS5`,`iOS6` & `IOS7`, and it's working perfectly fine.

However, when we are trying to use app in **2G network** and try to call an adapter procedure it is not even connecting to the server. Every time we are getting a time out and after trying 10-15 times, it will get connect to server and give response back.

When we use same app **on other good network or 3G**, it works perfectly fine with no issue.

This is the log which we se in Xcode Organizer console while using 2G network:

```
Jan 17 16:50:53 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: WLRequestBuilder.initWithRootUrl else_url: https://domain.com:443/MyApp/apps/services/api/MyApp/ipad/0/query
Jan 17 16:50:55 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: LSHelperClient: Session started with polling: NO
Jan 17 16:50:59 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.
Jan 17 16:50:59 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: [ERROR] Worklight: -[WLRequest requestFailed:]:338::Status code='0' error='The request timed out'
Jan 17 16:50:59 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.
Jan 17 16:50:59 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.
Jan 17 16:50:59 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: [ERROR] Worklight: -[WLClient onInvokeProcedureFailure:userInfo:]:696::response string=''
Jan 17 16:50:59 My-iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleAP3GDL::handleInterrupt2 FIFO is Empty
Jan 17 16:51:08 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: WLRequestBuilder.initWithRootUrl else_url: https://domain.com:443/MyApp/apps/services/api/MyApp/ipad/0/query
Jan 17 16:51:14 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.
Jan 17 16:51:14 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: [ERROR] Worklight: -[WLRequest requestFailed:]:338::Status code='0' error='The request timed out'
Jan 17 16:51:14 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.
Jan 17 16:51:14 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.
Jan 17 16:51:14 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: [ERROR] Worklight: -[WLClient onInvokeProcedureFailure:userInfo:]:696::response string=''
Jan 17 16:51:17 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: WLRequestBuilder.initWithRootUrl else_url: https://domain.com:443/MyApp/apps/services/api/MyApp/ipad/0/query
Jan 17 16:51:23 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.
Jan 17 16:51:23 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: [ERROR] Worklight: -[WLRequest requestFailed:]:338::Status code='0' error='The request timed out'
Jan 17 16:51:23 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.
Jan 17 16:51:23 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x0000 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.
Jan 17 16:51:23 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: [ERROR] Worklight: -[WLClient onInvokeProcedureFailure:userInfo:]:696::response string=''
Jan 17 16:51:33 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: WLRequestBuilder.initWithRootUrl else_url: https://domain.com:443/MyApp/apps/services/api/MyApp/ipad/0/query
Jan 17 16:51:40 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: DeviceAuthManager:getWorklightUniqueDeviceId --> returning UUID from the keychain
Jan 17 16:51:40 My-iPad Sec Sec[292] <Warning>: WLRequestBuilder.initWithRootUrl else_url: https://domain.com:443/MyApp/apps/services/api/MyApp/ipad/0/query
```

Let me know what will be the issue and what else we can do for it. Our backend API is very fast, within millisecond we are getting response.

What we did on procedure side :

```
var timeout = 600000;
var invocationOptions = {
  onSuccess: LoginSuccess,
  onFailure: LoginFail,
  timeout: timeout
};
```

And in Adapter XML file :

```
<procedure name="Authentication" requestTimeoutInSeconds="600000"/>
```

And we have tried this experiment with HTTP and HTTPS both and having the same issue(getting time out).

When we launch app we are getting `wlclient init success`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not set high timeouts in adapter XML file. 600.000 seconds timeout means that a thread that is used to connect to a backend will wait for 166.6 hours before timing out, this can easily kill your server functionality:)

Usually you want your adapter<->backend timeout to be the highest value you allow in app<->adapter connectivity. E.g. if max timeout you use in your app is 60 seconds - this is the value to use in adapter<->backend segment as well.

Now, regarding app<->adapter segment. AFAIR default timeout is 30 seconds. This is usually enough for 2G networks as well. However in some cases this might be a bit low. You can use getNetworkInfo() API (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc%2Fhtml%2Frefjavascript-client%2Fhtml%2FWL.Device.html) to detect whether you're on WIFI/Mobile and 3g/2g etc. Once you're on a slow network - increase your timeouts. If you're on a fast network - there's no reasons to keep users waiting too long, reduce your timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

It's great that your *backend* is very fast, but that's an internal system.

When using 3G or WiFi, speeds are typically fast.
When using 2G or less, speeds are typically much slower.

Did you try increasing the timeout values in your `WL.Client.invokeProcedure` as well as adapter procedure?

These will allow for the client and/or server to wait longer for a response. This should help in cases where the network speed is very slow.

See these questions:

- [How to increase the adapter procedure timeout value in Worklight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807821/how-to-increase-the-adapter-procedure-timeout-value-in-worklight/15807997#15807997)
- [IBM Worklight 6.0.0.1 - Timeout setting in Adapters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326585/ibm-worklight-6-0-0-1-timeout-setting-in-adapters/20327279#20327279)

Comment: Yes , We have already tried these things but no use. After doing so much R&D and changes we are posting on Stackoverflow.

Comment: What does that mean? What settings did you try? Did you try for example 10 minutes on both the invokeProcedure and procedure and still it failed? Edit the question and elaborate on what "experiments" you've done because you did not mention this at all.

Comment: Also, did you try for the sake of experiment with HTTP rather than HTTPS? Is there a difference? And which function fails? Is this the login? the connect to server? some data retrieval procedure? what fails?

Comment: You will get wlclient init success regardless. This message is about the client framework and not the connection, so again, what fails - the connection to the server (what does this "authentication" function do?)? Is there a firewall or any other server or anything in your server architecture?

Comment: But if this is the case why the same app is working on other network. Yes we have firewall and other server.

Comment: Because 2G network is much much slower. Have you tried with higher timeout values in the client + adapter + backend? Right now this is the only thing I see here, that the network is very slow and you reach your timeout before the response arrives. What happens if you put 10 minutes or even higher as the timeout everywhere, does it still fail? When does it fail? does it reach the 10 minutes or fails before it? and if it fails before it - check why. this could lead to where the timeout is not set high enough or tell you where you have a problem in your setup.

Comment: Yes we have put 10 minute also , we after 10 minute also it is getting time out. I am surprised why it is happening even after 10 min.

Comment: Did you ask your IT department to profile the network and see where it takes so long? This really looks to me like there is something in your network that causes the slow response

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45466/discussion-between-vishal-g-and-idan-adar)