# IBM Worklight - 6.1 How to stop first adapter call while making second adapter call

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

**If we fire multiple adapter call with the gap of  2 -3 sec then how to to stop first call which is running in background** ?

Lets say : 
I am calling `A-Adapter` which gives some data after success but at the same time with a gap of 2-3 second if i call `B-Adapter` which gives some small data within millisecond.

But still the first adapter call is taking time and respond back after 4 second or suppose timed out. Now we are getting success or failure of `A-Adapter` after `B-Adapter` success.

Now My doubt is

Can we stop or unsubscribe first adapter call at some point of time whenever required ?

Is there anything in worklight for doing this ?

Issue which we are facing right now is major issue, given below.

Lets say :

I am calling login adapter which gives login success or failure and it is taking some time let say 5 minutes. So what i did i close the app and launched the application again. 
I again clicked on login and i am getting successful login and now i am inside the app and doing some work. Now at this point of time , I am getting failure response of login adapter which was taking time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your direct question is, no, there is no API that will let you terminate an adapter procedure invocation that is in progress, prior to when it finishes on it's own.  Once an adapter procedure is invoked, it must either succeed, fail, or time out.

Where you discuss the possibility of A-adapter finishing after B-adapter, I could not tell if you just intended that as an observation regarding a situation that could possibly occur, or if you see it as a problem or a bug - if the latter, you should understand that since adapter procedure invocations are completely asynchronous, there is no guarantee that adapter procedures will finish in the order they are invoked, and there is not intended to be any such guarantee.

In order to handle the issue you have described, what I would suggest would be to use an invocationContext to make sure that, when your success or failure callback fires, that this corresponds to an adapter procedure invocation that you are expecting a response for, and to ignore the result if it does not.  Fore more information, see the section of the Worklight Information Center that describes [the options Object](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/apiref/r_the_options_object.html).

If the usual, "normal" response time of the adapter procedure is small, you could also try to mitigate this issue by setting the procedure invocation timeout to a small amount of time.  So, for instance, if an adapter procedure normally completes within about 4 seconds, maybe set the timeout to 15 seconds - assuming that, if the adapter procedure hasn't finished after that amount of time, something is wrong (maybe the back-end system you're retrieving data from has hung or crashed, or something like that) and it's just going to eventually fail anyway, so just let it return a timeout failure and give up.  That way, you don't need to worry about what happens when it eventually fails some minutes later...  There was [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807821/how-to-increase-the-adapter-procedure-timeout-value-in-worklight) asked in the past, where it was explained how to change this timeout.