# Using setTimeout in Worklight adapter procedure

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I've tried to use **setTimeout** in Worklight adapter procedure. It doesn't work.

```
WLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project BusinessBank]PushAdapter/submitNotificationFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project BusinessBank]
ReferenceError: "setTimeout" is not defined. (PushAdapter-impl.js#37)
```

I need to hold sending the push notification after invoking adapter procedure. It's need for the demo. My code example:

```
WL.Server.createEventSource({
    name: 'PushEventSource',
    onDeviceSubscribe: 'deviceSubscribeFunc',
    onDeviceUnsubscribe: 'deviceUnsubscribeFunc',
    securityTest:'AngularStarter-strong-mobile-securityTest'
});

function deviceSubscribeFunc(userSubscription, deviceSubscription){}
function deviceUnsubscribeFunc(userSubscription, deviceSubscription){}

function submitNotification(userId, notificationText) {
    var userSubscription = WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription('PushAdapter.PushEventSource', userId);

    if (userSubscription == null) {
        return { result: "No subscription found for user :: " + userId };
    }

    var badgeDigit = 1,
        notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notificationText, badgeDigit, {custom: "data"});

    setTimeout(function() {
        WL.Logger.debug("submitNotification >> userId :: " + userId + ", text :: " + notificationText);
        WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, notification);
    },5000);

    return {
        result: "Notification sent to user :: " + userId
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're actually about about [JavaScript method `setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp), it will help if you'll add some code example of what *exactly* you're trying to do, given this is a programming Q&A website and all.

If you're demoing your app using Worklight Studio, there is no need to implement a timeout.
Open the app, login, subscribe to notifications, close the app.  Then, right-click on the adapter and select Run As > Invoke Worklight procedure and add a username in text (for example: "myuser","mytext"). And that's it... the notification will be sent. Whenever you want it to be sent.

Otherwise,
There is no such thing as `setTimeout` for an adapter procedure...

See here: [How to increase the adapter procedure timeout value in Worklight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807821/how-to-increase-the-adapter-procedure-timeout-value-in-worklight)

To set a timeout to a procedure, in the adapter XML file:

```
<procedure name="nameHere" requestTimeoutInSeconds="valueHere"/>
```

Please review the [IBM Worklight Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNJXP/welcome.html) and [training modules](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_server_dev).

Comment: I have a problem with the push demo. I need to demonstrate this Worklight feature and I want to hold the sending message after invoking the adapters procedure for 4-5 second.

Comment: I need a time to close the app and show the received push notification. I can't set timer in the app code, because the adapter will not be invoked.

Comment: Why do you need a timer? Just close the app, then right-click the adapter in Worklight Studio and select Run As > Invoke Worklight adapter. There you input the username and message, "idan,"some message". That's it

Comment: I need a timer for demonstration a receiving Push. For customers Push is something, what is coming in the Notification Center or on the Lock Screen. So when I present my Demo App, some actions invoke Push adapter procedure. And I need a time to close the app and show the received notification. I can't on the demonstation run the laptop, open eclipse and invoke the adapter procedure.

Comment: Before, you asked to put a timer in the ADAPTER code. The adapter is part of the SERVER, not the application. Now, you mention you want a timer on the CLIENT invoke procedure? You need to be very clear about WHAT exactly you want, because you are not clear at all. As Anton explained, you cannot use setTimeout in the ADAPTER code.

Comment: Re-think the way you present your application. Right now it doesn't make sense.

Comment: And if you mean that you have specialized code in your APPLICATION (client) that somehow tells the server to send a push notification, then you can try to use Cordova's PAUSE event to do something when the app is put in the background, like - invoking the code that "sends the push".

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout API belongs to a global window object. basically using it the way you do is a shortcut to window.setTimeout().

Since adapter is not a browser but a server runnable code it doesn't have a global window object, therefore you have no setTimeout API.